# date annotations [Authorize] not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I'm trying to deploy the validation logins for active directory groups. as shown below

```
// Control with groups restriction of the ad
[Authorize (Roles = "Financial, ADM")]
public class FinanceiroController: Controller
{

}
```

I'm using FormsAuthentication to login:

```
Principal User = autenticacao.Autenticar (login, password);
if (User! = null)
{
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie (login, true);
}
```

the problem is that I can not access the same controller using a user q is the ADM group, someone help me?

Comment: You are missing something like: `Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, roleName); `

Comment: after or before of "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie (login, true);"

Comment: did you assign ADM Role to q user. check it.

Comment: After...it should be something like: `Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Current().Name, roleName);`

Comment: Hackerman, I am using the class: PrincipalContext, UserPrincipal,.

Comment: yes, The ADM Role was assigned to user